# How to do a telethon login using GUI

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm new to telethon, and I'm trying to make a GUI for my application using python.

The problem is when I run this code:

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient

id = ******
hash = *******

client = TelegramClient("test",id,hash)

client.start()
```

it automatically runs a terminal login, so I can't actually use that in a GUI.

I also saw :

```
client.start(phone=your_phone_callback,password=your_password_callback,code_callback=your_code_callback)
```

I don't really understand how to get the confirmation code at the first place.

How to do a telethon login using GUI?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`gui.py` Telethon example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/v1/telethon_examples/gui.py). Note how it doesn't use `with` or `start`, as those are interactive in the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `client.start()`

use

```
   client = TelegramClient(f"session", api_id, api_hash)
   await client.connect()
    
   #phone = <User phone number>

   # This will send the code to the user. You have to get it using the front end
   phone_code = await client.send_code_request(phone)
   
   phone_code_hash = phone_code.phone_code_hash

   #code = <Code from the user>

   await client.sign_in(phone, code=code, phone_code_hash=phone_code_hash)
```

this will log you in without using the terminal.